# Why is event-log time different from taskbar time?

Tags: windows, event-log

Today is the first time in several months that I've opened up Administrative tools to view the event log.

Imagine my consternation when I saw events in the log with a time-stamp of 11/09/2012. The task-bar/control-panel date/time settings show what appears to be the correct date and time i.e. January 22, 2012 ADG 10:27 AM (GMT+0530). This is a standalone box.

The 'Internet Zone' tab in Control-panel/Date-and-time settings states *'The time has been successfully synchronized with time.nist.gov on 20/01/2012 17:05'*

Most recent entry in the event log is a W32Time event time-stamped 11/09/2012 12:10:19 that states *'The time service has detected that the system time needs to be  changed by -62985605 seconds. The time service will not change the system  time by more than -54000 seconds. Verify that your time and time zone  are correct, and that the time source time.nist.gov (ntp.m|0x1|59.95.77.95:123->192.43.244.18:123) is working properly.'*

I'm flummoxed.

1. Why is the event log time different from the system/task-bar time?
2. Why is the event log report apparently in conflict with the report under Internet Zone tab in Control-panel/Date and Time settings?

Answer (score 6):

The future-dated entries are not in fact your most recent.

They just happen to be at the top because at one stage, your computer did think it was later this year.

62985605 seconds equates to exactly 729 days. So on or around 11/09/2010, your computer thought it was 2012 (I don't know if this is MM/DD or DD/MM hence my "on or around").

Comment: it's DD/MM. The thing is, there are no entries in there between 2010, and 2012 ...

Comment: Well since I can't see your computer, and you haven't told us when the date was changed to the correct value, there's nothing more I can suggest. However, I stand by my answer.

Comment: No argument against your answer. It's just there isn't any record between 11/09/2010 and 11/09/2012 in the system event log

Comment: No offence taken. It's not easy to assume why this would be the case. While I understand your confusion, without seeing the machine in front of me, I'd have to pass on a more complete answer.